# Content_type error displaying twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the content type error message twice, How can I errase the second one?

```
Document content type is not an acceptable type of document only pdf
Document ["is not an acceptable type of document only pdf"]
```

I tried doing this (like I saw in other post) :

```
  @document.errors.delete(:document)
```

But it erases the two errors. This is the code  I use for the validation :

```
  validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ["application/pdf"], :message => 'is not an acceptable type of document only pdf'
```

This is the code I use to display the errors

**An error ocurred**

```
<ul class="ml-30">
    <% @errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    <li>Please change a few things up and try submitting again.</li>
</ul>
```

How can I jus t display just the correct error message?

Comment: That's the validation... but where is the code you are using to display the errors? Also - what's this `validates_attachment_content_type` validation? is that a method you've gotten from a library somewhere? Because it sure isn't a standard rails validation :) if you can show us that code - perhaps we can fix it.

Comment: @Flezcano Can you share the view code where you are displaying the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the :message part so it is just.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => ["application/pdf"]
```

The first message will still be there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you say, and now I receive the first error and another one saying 'Document [is invalid]'

Comment: Here's how you can remove that message. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3707274/1905235