# Rails 4 after_validation Error Messages Generic 'is invalid'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-errors

How do you remove the generic 'is invalid' error messages in Rails 4?

For instance if I have a client model, with name and password as attributes, I would get:

```
Client name can not be blank
Client password can not be blank
Client is Invalid
```

The Client is invalid is not really needed, but I can't seem to get rid of them.

I've tried various suggestions from here:

[Rails: Getting rid of generic "X is invalid" validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947365/rails-getting-rid-of-generic-x-is-invalid-validation-errors)

But none are working. I'm using locales to make the error messages I want say the right text, but just can't knock the generic ones on the head.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When are you seeing these - is it when calling a specific helper to list the error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to change rails' built-in text is via the locale-specific language rules, ie your `config/locales/en.yml` file.

Finding the key-path down to the text you want can be tricky sometimes.  Here's an example from a project where i did this, a while ago.  It's a rails2 project so the structure of the keys may have changed since.

```
#in config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      full_messages:
        format: "{{message}}"    
      #define standard error messages, which we can overide on per model/per attribute basis further down
      messages:
        record_invalid: "Validation failed: {{errors}}"    
      models:
        user_session:
          blank: "{{attribute}} can not be blank"
          attributes:
            login:
              invalid: "Please enter your user name"   
            password:
              invalid: "Please note that passwords are case sensitive"  
        user:
          blank: "{{attribute}} can not be blank"
          attributes:
            login:
              invalid: "User Name can only contain letters and numbers and -, @, . or _ symbols"   
              available: username available
              unavailable: username already taken
```

EDIT: the links in this section of the i18n docs show you rails' built in en.yml structure, so to make changes you can copy the built-in into your own en.yml, and delete everything except the bits you've changed (for clarity's sake).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module

Comment: I've managed to change the text fine on the error messages I want, I just need to completely remove the generic validation errors. Thanks though

Comment: ah i see - sorry.  Did you add " I'm using locales to make the error messages I want say the right text" to your question after posting, or did i just not notice?

Comment: You missed it - I did write it in a funny place though! I've actually solved the problem anyway by taking the error messages inline, it automatically doesn't show the generic one. Cheers